# How to collide a circle against a pixel grid without getting snagged?

Tags: character-controller, physx

It's probably senseless to post my code because it simply takes a hard-stop approach when it encounters anything in the grid that is impassable (well, I've attempted to check -20/+20 deg, then -40/+40 deg, then -60/60 to see if it got around the obstacle but that didn't work)  There is no salvaging my current point-sized collider code so I am here seeking code that works, sliding smoothly along edges and not getting stuck.  From what I'm reading, a circle should be used for 2D (or capsule for 3D) for the character collider but I'm not sure how to implement collisions with a pixel grid (bitmap).  Do I let the circle penetrate somewhat and check all collisions within the radius?  How do I guide my character based on those collisions?  Does anyone have any sample code for that?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing a collide and slide algorithm (sometimes also called move & slide). I'm not presently familiar with the PhysX API, but I found [this documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/CharacterControllers.html#:%7E:text=The%20particular%20behavior%20it%20implemented%20is%20often%20called,a%20robust%20and%20well-known%20behavior%20for%20character%20control.) from nVidia discussing it in the context of character controllers.

A (CCT) SDK is an external component built on top of the PhysX SDK, in a manner similar to PhysXExtensions.

The full documentation is extensive and too long to cover here, so I'm going to focus on their argument for using CCT at all.

The main advantage of kinematic controllers is that they do not suffer from the following issues, which are typical for dynamic controllers:

- (lack of) continuous collision detection which can lead to notorious 'tunneling effect' problems:

  - if the character goes too fast it might tunnel through a wall
  - as a consequence, the character's maximum velocity be limited (thus also limiting the game play possibilities)
  - even if it does not tunnel, the character might jitter in various cases
- No direct control: a rigid body is typically controlled with impulses or forces.
- Trouble with friction: when the character is standing on a ramp, it should not slide.
- Trouble with restitution (bouncing from fast collisions): typically, restitution should be avoided for CCTs.
- Undesired jumps: characters must often stick to the ground, no matter what the physical behavior should be - for example leaving a ramp at a high speed the physics engine often makes the character jump a bit, but that is often not the desired behavior.
- Undesired rotations: a typical character is always standing up and never rotating. However physics engines often have poor support for that sort of constraints, and a great deal of effort is often put into preventing a capsule around the character from falling (it should always stands up on its tip).

To summarize, a lot of effort can be spent on tweaking and disabling the physics engine's features simply to emulate what is otherwise a much less complex piece of custom code. It is natural to instead keep using that simple piece of custom code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  My algorithm doesn't suffer from the "tunneling" effect because it "replays" the character movement from XYZ1 to XYZ2 by crawling at  an increment slightly smaller than my voxel size.  Also friction isn't an issue because I am matching the client's gravity slide speed based on the slope.  That's actually the coolest part of my extremely authoritative server mimicking client movements.  I suffer from the issue of sliding and not getting snagged on impassable voxels.  Besides reimplementing the entire PhysX controller, I'm hoping for a somewhat close shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested ---
I'm happy with my own solution rather than implementing a full character collider (circle/capsule).  I try the path forward with my single point collider.  If it doesn't even make it the attempted dist*0.2f, I ground raycast 0.3f meters left and 0.3 meters right of my character (L/R based on character's heading, or location rotation).  If either of these raycasts move any distance at all, I then attempt a forward move in the same direction as the middle vector (my character).  Out of the 3, whichever forward vector makes it the furthest without collision wins and that is where I move my character to.  I played around with this for 15 minutes straight, purposely running into stuff and through tight spaces, up and down stairs, etc, and only got stuck 1 time.

Comment: If the character being a circle was not a requirement, you should remove it from the title of the question.

Comment: Well, it still would be nice to have a circle collider that is efficient.  The path I went down was getting ridiculous.  I'm happy I hardly get stuck but would love to see other people's solutions for the circle collider.  For now, I'm going with my solution.